# Firebase image retrieval Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

so basically i want to retrive an image from firebase i have already done the upload function and when i retrieve the image i get the info and the image view is white with no picture shown with this error shown
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/lost-and-found-bfbbc.firebaseio.com/UID/Users/1/imageid (No such file or directory)
W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:

below is the code of the retrieve

```
 RtBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
//                        String name = snapshot.child(uid.get()).child("name").getValue().toString();
//                        String phone = snapshot.child(uid.get()).child("phone").getValue().toString();
//                        String iid = snapshot.child(uid).child("imageid").getValue().toString();
//                        a.setText(name);
//                        b.setText(phone);
//                          det = snapshot.child(haha).child("dett").getValue().toString();
//
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String name = ds.getKey();
                            String k = snapshot.child(name).child("Users").child("1").child("dett").getValue().toString();
                            //a.setText(k);

                            if(k.equals("none")){
                                Toast.makeText(LookActivity.this,"Sorry, nobody was found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
//                                snapshot.child(det);
//                                String nam = snapshot.child(det).child("Users").child("1").child("name").getValue().toString();
//                                String phn = snapshot.child(det).child("Users").child("1").child("phone").getValue().toString();
//                                a.setText(nam);
//                                b.setText(phn);
                                  String nam = snapshot.child(k).child("Users").child("1").child("name").getValue().toString();
                                  String phn = snapshot.child(k).child("Users").child("1").child("phone").getValue().toString();
                                  Uri imgg = Uri.parse(snapshot.child(k).child("Users").child("1").child("imageid").getRef().toString());
                                  a.setText(nam);
                                  b.setText(phn);
                                  mImageView.setImageURI(imgg);

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Is there really only a single `/` after `https:`?

Comment: yes but the point is the im calling a certain variable and its not shown and given the error above

Comment: The point I was making is that `https:/lost-and-found-bfbbc...` is an invalid URL.  There should be two `/` characters.

Comment: how do i edit this then because im not famillier of where to add it